# why finally block doesn't execute?

Tags: java, finally

Why finally block of this code does not execute? it only prints 1. Is finally block not execute after `System.exit(0);` ?

```
    void method2() {
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        System.exit(0);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Code doesn't continue to execute after an application terminates.  Why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.exit(0) actually stops execution of the program entirely. Remove System.exit as you aren't actually trying to exit your code there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove SYSTEM.EXIT because that exits the entire program regardless of what is after it. Though it is in a Try it still enters the block of code :)

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit(0)` terminates the runtime before the `finally` block is even executed. Move it to `finally` block after your `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit();` shuts down the virtual machine. The only thing that can be executed after this is a shutdown hook created with `Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)`.